# Query a large number of large records

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have a situation I'm working on where I'm querying our database and returning possibly 20k records, where each record has a configuration file that ranges in size from 10,000 bytes to 1  megabyte.  So the amount of data is very large possibly.  I'm not trying to display this information to users, so that is not a concern.   I'm basically running this as a scheduled task to check for certain lines within these configurations.

The problem I'm running into however, is when my record counts get high I can run into a `System.OutOfMemoryException`.  I have a single query that locates all the rows I need at one time and obviously this is not working well.  I'm looking for suggestions on how to query these rows efficiently without running out of memory.  I've considered getting a list of all the rows I'll need then looping over the results and just pulling the configurations one row at a time, but that doesn't seem very efficient?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you just break it down so that you get 1000 records at a time?

Comment: I can.  I'm just looking for suggestions or examples of better solutions.  Whether I get them 1 or 1000 at a time.

Comment: why you want to do this as scheduled task, can't you do something when  something change in related table?

Comment: I don't control the data that is coming into the table.  So something that was there yesterday might not be there today and something entire new might appear.

Comment: @KyleRogers - I believe that Damith was suggesting that you could add triggers to the appropriate tables so that you could be notified of changes rather than having to hunt them down.  Is the check for "certain lines" something that you can do in TSQL?  Or perhaps in a CLR function in SQL Server?

Comment: Not exactly a programming solution, but have you considered adding more RAM to the box?  Or, have you verified that the RAM on that box is correctly configrued for your enviornment.  Sometimes it's more cost-effecient to just throw hardware at the problem :)

Comment: it does seem that a trigger approach might be good - as long as the items in the files that you are looking for do not change.

Comment: @KyleRogers I don't think you really have another choice. You either need to reduce the data you're bringing over (which doesn't seem like an option), or you need to process part of the data at a time.

Comment: You are running this as a scheduled task to check for certain lines within these configurations right? How about writing a query that returns you those specific lines alone instead of the entire record?